# Unable to load local html file in WebView2

Tags: winforms, webview2

Trying loading HTML from Bin>Debug>html folder.
Want to achieve loading HTML from any location from the project package.

Code -

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;

namespace WebViewPOC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initWebView();
        }

        async void initWebView()
        {
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Path.Combine("file:", Application.StartupPath, "html", "index.html"));
        }

    }
}
```

[Output and location of HTML](https://harsh-sprious.tinytake.com/msc/NzcxOTEyMl8yMDczNzM3MQ)

Comment: `webView21.Source = new Uri("[HTML File path]");` -- Your initialization procedure is not correct. Override `OnLoad()` or subscribe to the `Load` event, make that method async, don't call a pseudo-async `void` method from the Form's Constructor

Comment: Hi Jimi, Thank you from the reply, I figured out the issue,  Instead of a Path I had to use System.IO.Path in CoreWebView2.Navigate() function